# M2: Sending data by clicking Next on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I had some customization on Shipping page of checkout on Magento2, now I want to send out some data back to my module by the user hitting "Next" button and add to the current cart, so in which way should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you progress from the 'Shipping' step to the 'Review & Payment' step, an API request is sent to this function `\Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement::saveAddressInformation`. You can view the js that sends the request here `Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model\shipping-save-processor\default.js'

To send data to your module you can write a plugin for the saveAddressInformation method. For more information on how to write a plugin, see this documentation page:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: one question, I tried to alert out the url of the post request in the above mentioned default.js file(which is resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote)) and got rest/default/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information. Could you explain its meaning?

Comment: If you look in Magento/Checkout/etc/webapi.xml you will see several routes. The url you got in your alert points to the shipping-information route which defines which service will receive the payload. You can read more about the webapi.xml configuration file here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Comment: Million thanks, I will try this out and tell you if this works :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a module
2. Use an obsever on the right event
3. Implement your code for the observer to make the changes you wish

See for more details: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-observers.html

Here is al list of events: http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

I think you are looking for `checkout_cart_product_add_after` but I am not sure depending on your explanation.