# Magento2: Getting the shipping address input box values in Review & Payments section

Tags: magento2, php

I am creating a module in magento2. Currently my planning is when user will provide the shipping address detail and will click the next button, in back-end I will get the address given by the user , according to that I will send a api request to the shipping api, so that when user views the Reviews and payment section, I can show him/her when the product will be delivered.

But as per above plan, I am stuck at how to handle the next button click and getting the address input.

Please give some hints. So that I can proceed.

I have gone through the discussion in [M2: Sending data by clicking Next on checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96788/m2-sending-data-by-clicking-next-on-checkout). But Not getting any information.

Also searched in google. But no result.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement custom shipping module, you don't need any additional handlers to get a shipping address. In this case, you need to implement shipping provider like in [the sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-shipping-provider).

If you want to implement some module, which uses shipping address for own purposes you need to used plugins.

In your case it should be plugin for the `\Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation` and it should be configured to call before main method execution. Something like this:

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestShippingInformationManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="some_name_of_plugin" type="PluginClassName" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And it the plugin class you need to implement the `before` method:

```
class Plugin{

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(GuestShippingInformationManagementInterface $management, $cartId, ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation)
    {
       //do something here
    }
}
```

For more additional information, please, see [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) plugins section.